# When submitting form in react native, whether to pass form values as params or get the values by setting state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have all my states in my parent `App.js`. I have initialized states like so.

```
 this.state = {
   name: ''            
 }
```

I have a child component `Child.js` which is stateless.
Now I have a form in `Child.js` and when submitted, calls function `onSubmit()` which then sends data to my database.
There are two ways by which the data can be passed from the child component to the `onSubmit` function. I can pass the data as argument from Child.js and then use it as parameter in my App.js like this.

Child.js

```
  <Button
     title="Save"
     onPress={() => this.props.onSubmit(myformvalue)}
  />
```

After this, I can just use the values as parameter in my `onSubmit` function like this.

```
  onSubmit (value) {
      fetch('myip', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
           customername: value,
      }),
    }
  }
```

OR,
I can create a function in App.js that tracks the state change in Child.js's form and then use the current state when submitting like this.

App.js

```
  changingstatefunc(NameParameter) {
    this.setState ({
      name: NameParameter,
   })
  }

  onSubmit () {
      fetch('myip', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
           customername: this.state.name,
      }),
    }
  }
```

And In Child.js,

```
         <TextInput
                placeholder="Customer Name"
                onChangeText={(customername) => this.props.changingstatefunc(customername)}
          />
```

I am not sure which one to choose as both work. In React.js they want you to use controlled input but in react-native, would it be okay to just use the first method to pass parameters instead of changing states if I do not need anything special to happen on each press of a button?

Comment: Preferred way use setState. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html. controller component

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution - create stateful `Child` component and control all inputs in this component, and `onSubmit` just pass data from `Child` state to `App`. It'll allow you to validate inputs in the `Child` component and the `App` component will be much readable

Comment: Yeah my App.js is starting to look messy. But where would onSubmit be? That could stay in the child component too right? Im worried about my app being non scaleable.